Language and language storage system reflecting non-linear brain structure
Consider the following sentence.
"A sailor {went, ate, made, tailored} to see see see and {did, wanted, embedded-inspired} what they could do"
Now, suppose that instead of having a book I have a computer.
I turn each node in this sentence into a node in a graph, and display it it (including the set structure).
Then, I branch the elements of the "set, nodes(?.
The branches, lead to other sentences (sentence continuation
I regard the entire graph as what I want to say.
I use something like vision or something like TalkBack to go through the graph, which, does away with order (in some ways. It's a graph, it's non liner.
Has anyone implemented software to support this type of language construction.
Please create the accessibility tag for me. Don't just assume a language is liner or don't comprehend and include reading considerations.
Thanks.

What would you want the software to do, specifically, to support this?

For example my first thought would be something involving GraphViz, since that's useful for almost anything involving drawing graphs, but that only helps if your goal is drawing it out.

Your description sound almost like dependency parsing, analyzing the sentence as a tree (acyclic graph), although on a different level (not syntax).
This is well established in (corpus) linguistics, and subsequently there are some (not many, though) tools for intractive tree editing - se e.g. a list of tools working with Universal Dependencies. And often you are not restricted to the existing tagset (and dependency relations), but you can use your own.
Warning, since the tools are often "research quality" and used in a rather niche environment, installing and using them is sometimes not for the faint of heart.

It sounds like you want software to support writing, viewing, and editing a non-linear language.
Miss Rosette
The descriptions I've seen of "Miss Rosette" seem like exactly what you're looking for -- it's software to support writing and editing "The Elephant's Memory"(a)(b)(c), a 2D non-linear language.
Alas, I've only found descriptions of it; I've never seen the software itself.
General 2D drawing software
My understanding is that many people use general-purpose drawing software (such as, for example, Inkscape or Vectr using a "library of symbols") to create written text that is even a little outside the capabilities of a linear word-processor.
Specialized 2D drawing software
There are a lot of specialized tools to make 2D non-linear diagrams.
Perhaps they are close enough that they could be (mis-)used directly
as software to support writing a 2D non-linear language.
Some of this software is open-source,
so perhaps they could be tweaked to better support
writing 2D non-linear languages in general,
or specialized to better support some specific 2D non-linear language.

Tools for "schematic capture" and "PCB layout" (generating 2D non-linear images called "schematic diagrams" and "PCB artwork", respectively) include, for example, gEDA and KiCad. Often they represent "activities" where lots of different things are happening simultaneously.
Tools for mapping computer networking include, for example, draw.io (also known as diagrams.net) and ASCIIFlow and Mermaid.
Tools for "technical drawings" also called "mechanical drawings" include, for example, LibreCAD and QCAD and FreeCAD and the 2D parts of JSCAD.
Tools for 2D chemistry drawings of molecules include, for example, the 2D parts of MolView.

